# What do we call the person who gives a beggar money?

Tags: single-word-requests

A beggar is a person who beg for getting money or something from a person but what do we call that person who gives the beggar the money ?

Like Hop-ons are people who jump onto the back of the stair car for a free ride.

In the question, I mean people who gives money not always or gives money in an irregular form, like not giving donation at a particular time/date or day.

Comment: Generous, loving

Comment: Donor, benefactor, giver, etc.

Comment: How is giving spare change getting a free ride?

Comment: If a distortion is called for, you could negate the charity by saying they are enablers, or looking for bragging rights, or virtue signaling. But I wouldn't. One idea is to give only if you can express kindness like "God bless you." If not, maybe you got guilted into it.

Comment: I think the answer you're after depends on what you're intending to imply about the giver with the word. Do you want to say that they're being generous/charitable by giving (positive), that they're maybe too sympathetic/gullible in giving to the beggar (neutral-ish), that they're being exploited by the beggar/enabling the beggar's 'bad lifestyle' (negative), or that they're only giving with bad/selfish intentions (negative again). Lots of answers are possible depending on the context.

Comment: While the question itself, as formulated in the first sentence, is fairly clear, it is rather unclear what the second sentence has to do with it, and what precisely is meant by the third one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"*Benefactor*" appears to be the most likely term.

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/benefactor?q=benefactor)) a person who gives money or other help to a person or an organization such as a school or charity
> ♦ a generous benefactor
> ♦ The equipment was funded by friends and benefactors of the hospital.

---

*Additions in view of delimiting better the scope of the term "benefactor", delimiting that the comments to the present question suggest ([**user  DhruboZ**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/566772/what-do-we-call-the-person-who-gives-a-beggar-money/566773?noredirect=1#comment1405736_566773))*

It is true that "benefactor" is a term that applies to acts of giving of several sorts, not just the act of giving alms, which concerns specifically enough beggars and certain cases of  persons in dire need. Nevertheless, it does apply to beggary.

- These are thy sports, Fortune! to elevate the beggar; to deride his benefactor. ([The Beggar and His Benefactor, 1809](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_Beggar_and_His_Benefactor/-5ZBAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22benefactor%22&printsec=frontcover))

It seems to me that it matters not at all whether the act of alms giving is occasional or regular and whether or not regularly repeated for the same beggar (not so rarely, this is the case).

Further, there is a question of idiomaticity that could be looked at. If one were to refer to such a person who gives alms as they stand in relation to the receiver, it wouldn't be as idiomatic to use phrases such as "my almsgiver", "his almsgivers"; "almsgiver" is, by the way,  a term that makes abstaction of  the idea of  goodness that characterizes  the act, a more neutral term, that nonetheless can have a place in the present context; "my benefactor", "his benefactors" would be more natural. There is a certain certitude of this fact to be gained in the information provided by the following ngrams.

([my benefactor,my almsgiver](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=my+almsgiver%2Cmy+benefactor&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmy%20benefactor%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmy%20benefactor%3B%2Cc0))
([my benefactors,my almsgivers](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=my+almsgivers%2Cmy+benefactors&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmy%20benefactors%3B%2Cc0))
([his benefactor,his almsgiver](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=his+almsgiver%2Chis+benefactor&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chis%20almsgiver%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chis%20benefactor%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Chis%20almsgiver%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chis%20benefactor%3B%2Cc0))
([his benefactors,his almsgivers](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=his+almsgivers%2Chis+benefactors&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chis%20benefactors%3B%2Cc0))
([their benefactors,their almsgivers](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=their+almsgivers%2Ctheir+benefactors&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctheir%20benefactors%3B%2Cc0))

It can be remarked from the third reference in the five preceding ones and from [this page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22his%20benefactor%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) that there exists a usage of the possessive "his" for "almsgiver", but it is rare in comparison with the usage with "benefactor" and  it is of quite recent origin (very rare in the past). This tends to show that no substantial  usage for this type of phrase exists that would be on the point of beginning to displace the traditional one.

Comment: This word sounds like the person gives/gift seldoms, https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/benefactor.html

Comment: @DhruboZ Your question makes no mention of how often something is given to a beggar... if you wanted to exclude one-off or occasional gifts, you should have said so in the question.

Comment: @DhruboZ I added some more facts to my answer; comment space is too small for that anyway.

Comment: As the question is closed, I can not edit the question anymore and add some other points but the answer of yours have made me satisfy my need.  Thanks you ...

Comment: @DhruboZ, closing a question does not preclude editing it. Closed questions sometimes get reopened after the editing that makes them clearer.

Answer (score 12):

**"almsgiver"** is specific for the situation you describe.

> - [almsgiver](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/almsgivers) - a person who gives alms.
> - [alms](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alms) - something (such as money or food) given freely to relieve the poor.
>   e.g. distributing alms to the needy

Comment: This is more suitable word for those who gives alms sometimes right ?

Comment: The typical giver of the price of a coffee isn't usually called an 'almsgiver'. Archaic at best. [Google ngrams for 'beggar', 'almsgiver'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beggar%2Calmsgiver&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbeggar%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Calmsgiver%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: While it is true that *almsgiver* (like *alms* itself) has a somewhat archaic feel to it, it has an important advantage over the terms offered in the other answers, in that it has traditionally been used for those who give small amounts of cash either directly to an individual or through a small-scale organisation (which is what the question is about). Using *benefactor, patron,* or *donor* in such cases would be excessively formal (although not entirely incorrect); these words are typically used for those who give larger amounts to relatively large charitable organisations.

Answer (score 1):

It's less optimal than "almsgiver", but you could stretch "patron" to fit: [OED](https://oed.com/view/Entry/138929)

> 5. a. A person or organization that uses money or influence to advance the interests of a person, cause, art, etc. …
>    c. A person who supports or frequents a business or other institution; a customer of a shop, restaurant, theatre, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A [**donor**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/donor) is

> a person or organization who gives something, especially money, to a charity, organization, or country that needs it.